# Scrolling to specific section of html page does not work

Tags: html, href

I am trying to specific sections using simple:

```
<li>
<a href="#about">About</a>
</li>
```

with the accompanying id="about" in the div in question. However it does not work. I tried to minimize the amount of work by using a bootstrap template that I am modifying only where needed. Do you have tips & tricks on what could cause this?

Thank you in advance for any help on this!

Comment: Should work fine unless you have duplicate IDs or JavaScript interfering. Post a [mcve] please

Comment: The template I am using is [Amoeba](https://bootstrapmade.com/free-one-page-bootstrap-template-amoeba/) There has been some other items in it that I needed to fix, but the scrolling to section problem seems to be in the template itself (i.e. tried downloading a new one and unzipped it just to find the same issue).